# onSubmit is not working inside dojox DialogSimple

Tags: dojo

i have following code

```
    var dlg = new dojox.widget.DialogSimple({
                "title": "my dialog",
                "style": "width: 800px;",
                "href":"some url"
                }).placeAt(dojo.body());

            dlg.show().then(function() {
                dlg.firstTime=true;
                var actionBar = dojo.create("div", {
                    "class": "dijitDialogPaneActionBar"
                 }, dlg.containerNode);

                 new dijit.form.Button({
                 "label": "Ok",
                   onClick: function(){
                       dojo.byId("inputForm").submit();
                    }
                 }).placeAt(actionBar);
                 new dijit.form.Button({
                   "label": "Cancel",
                   "type":"reset"
                 }).placeAt(actionBar

);
```

everything works fine untill the form submission.when ever i click the ok button form is submitting directly without calling the onSubmit event which i had written in the form page.

```
var form = dojo.byId("inputForm");
dojo.connect(form, "onsubmit", function(event){
   dojo.stopEvent(event);

  });
```

but when i submit the form with submit button ,which is inside the form,above code works well.How can i acheive the same thing with the action bar button click.

Comment: is the connect script before or after the form?  why dont you put the connect code in the show.then? you will be sure the dom is ready

Answer (score 0):

You have to have executeScripts:true set.

```
      var dlg = new dojox.widget.DialogSimple({
            "title": "my dialog",
            "style": "width: 800px;",
            "href":"some url",
            "executeScripts":true
            }).placeAt(dojo.body());
```